# How did they shoot the snow scenes in The Hunt?

Tags: film-techniques, the-hunt

How did they shoot the snow scenes in The Hunt? Did they use real snow, or is that a specific trick to fake it during the shooting?

Comment: You mean The Hunt aka Jagten?

Comment: Is there any snippet of video online that you could link to in your question?